# Minesweeper-type puzzle

Tags: mathematics

The premise is simple. We get a n*n matrix with numbers ranging from 0 to 16. The matrix is the result of a minesweeper-kind of addition whereby we have an original matrix containing numbers ranging from 0 to 3 and the second matrix is none else than the sum of the surrounding cells od the first matrix, wrapping around (i.e. $c_{0\_0}$ =  $c_{0\_1}$ +  $c_{1\_1}$  $c_{1\_0}$ +  $c_{1,2\_0}$ +  $c_{0\_2}$ +  $c_{2\_2}$ +  $c_{0\_0}$ +  $c_{2\_0}$

Example:

```
1 2 3
0 1 3
3 2 1
```

yields

```
15 14 13
16 15 13
13 14 15
```

How would you go about solving this mathematically for squares of arbitrary size 0 <= n < 100?

To clarify: the goal is to get the original matrix (shown first, containing only $0,1,2,3$) from the second matrix.

Comment: I believe "solving this" is finding the original matrix by the result? If that's so, you should specify it.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

**Edit:** Jaap Scherphuis made a insightful comment to show that

> Solving this matrix uniquely is not always possible when $n$ is even

Reasoning

> Consider the following matrix.
>
> ```
>  12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12
> ```
>
> One solution for this is as follows
>
> ```
>  0 1 2 3
>  1 2 3 0
>  2 3 0 1
>  3 0 1 2
> ```
>
> However, another perfectly valid solution is this
>
> ```
>  1 3 0 2
>  3 0 2 1
>  0 2 1 3
>  2 1 3 0
> ```
>
> This is due to the fact that the set of simultaneous equations governing the $n=4$ solution are not linearly independent (the rank of the matrix associated to the system is less than $16=n^2$).
>  This is the case whenever $n$ is even. As Jaap Scherpuis pointed out you could always use a checkerboard pattern using any distinct values for the two colours. For example, in the case $n=6$, we could have
>
> ```
>  0 3 0 3 0 3
>  3 0 3 0 3 0
>  0 3 0 3 0 3
>  3 0 3 0 3 0
>  0 3 0 3 0 3
>  3 0 3 0 3 0
> ```
>
> or we could have
>
> ```
>  1 2 1 2 1 2
>  2 1 2 1 2 1
>  1 2 1 2 1 2
>  2 1 2 1 2 1
>  1 2 1 2 1 2
>  2 1 2 1 2 1
> ```
>
> and both give rise to the grid
>
> ```
>  12 12 12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12 12 12
>  12 12 12 12 12 12
> ```
>
> so this result grid does not have a unique solution.

For the other cases

> There is an obvious strategy of inverting the system of simultaneous equations but this is quite difficult when $n$ is large (perhaps there is a clever shortcut to find the inverse of such large matrices). In any case, the matrix associated to the system of simultaneous equations seems to always be invertible when $n$ is odd (checked for a few small cases) so the solution is always uniquely determined (even among the reals).

For the case $n=3$

> We find that each entry is the sum of all other elements except for the entry in the same position. Hence, if are given a matrix, the strategy would be to take each entry away from its maximum value. Then, check if this is the solution and, if not, add 1 to each entry and check again until the solution is obtained.

For example

> In the case given in the question the given matrix is
>
> ```
>  15 14 13
>  16 15 13
>  13 14 15
> ```
>
> The maximum value is 16, and if we take all entries in the matrix away from 16, we get
>
> ```
>  1 2 3
>  0 1 3
>  3 2 1
> ```
>
> which is the solution.
>  Alternatively, if the given matrix were
>
> ```
>  16 16 16
>  16 16 16
>  16 16 16
> ```
>
> Then taking each entry from the maximum value yields
>
> ```
>  0 0 0
>  0 0 0
>  0 0 0
> ```
>
> which is not the solution, so we add 1 to each entry to get
>
> ```
>  1 1 1
>  1 1 1 
>  1 1 1
> ```
>
> which is again not the solution, but if we add 1 more we get
>
> ```
>  2 2 2
>  2 2 2 
>  2 2 2
> ```
>
> which is the solution.

Comment: A checkerboard is a nice counter example for even $n$ (use any two distinct values for the two colours).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah, yes of course, I have way overcomplicated this, haven't I?